# How to get product categories & its tree using REST api

Tags: rest, magento

I have to list all product categories in a page. From that list, a user will choose one of the categories to view the associated products.

1. Is it possible to read all product categories and its tree using REST API?
2. How can I differentiate promotion categories from the category list?

Comment: I think, we have to create new magento Rest api to get category list in magento.

Does any one have better solution?